# Deal with long numbers in scientific notation in json string - Freemarker

Tags: json, freemarker

I have a json string which contains a long number but in scientific notation (like 1.559101974041E12 instead of 1559101974041). Due to this, I am not able to parse it using ?eval as this value must be in double quotes in order to get parsed.

I thought of one solution like putting double quotes around them using regex and get them evaluated. After that, use some free marker method to convert value into long. But this solution is very risky and can alter other values as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your template looks, but if you have variable `s` that contains the string `"1.559101974041E12"` (the quotation marks aren't part of the string value itself), then you can parse it like `s?number`. `s?eval` doesn't work because scientific notation is not part of the FreeMarker syntax (but `?number` can parse more formats).

If you will re-print the number in the template, note that depending on locale and configuration settings, it might will look like `1,559,101,974,041`. You can prevent that with `?c` (for example like `${s?number?c}`), in which case it will always look like `1559101974041`.